Matching boot times from log using sed -E
I have the following issue. I want to compute average boot times from journalctl on a linux machine. I have already grepped only lines matching the required lines which look like this:
Sep 15 23:37:31 x systemd[1]: Startup finished in 15.751s (firmware) + 3.034s (loader) + 8.797s (kernel) + 17.169s (userspace) = 44.753s.
Sep 17 23:01:24 x systemd[1]: Startup finished in 13.976s (firmware) + 1.998s (loader) + 13.169s (kernel) + 12.014s (userspace) = 41.159s.
Sep 20 09:22:15 x systemd[1]: Startup finished in 19.200s (firmware) + 5.931s (loader) + 21min 29.490s (kernel) + 12.643s (userspace) = 22min 7.266s.
Sep 23 10:21:06 x systemd[1]: Startup finished in 13.140s (firmware) + 5.571s (loader) + 3min 44.479s (kernel) + 12.065s (userspace) = 4min 15.256s.
Sep 23 15:18:53 x systemd[1]: Startup finished in 15.277s (firmware) + 3.152s (loader) + 10.616s (kernel) + 33.766s (userspace) = 1min 2.812s.

Now I want to use sed -E to filter the startup  time, i.e. the last number. This is complicated by the fact that there are startup times over and under a minute. Here is what I tried so far:
1. sed -E "s/.*systemd\[1\]:.*(([0-9]+min)?[[:space:]]*[0-9]+\.[0-9]{3}s)/\1/"
2. sed -E "s/.*systemd\[1\]:.*(([0-9]+min)+[[:space:]]*[0-9]+\.[0-9]{3}s)/\1/"
3. sed -E "s/.*systemd\[1\]:.*((([0-9]+min[[:space:]]+)?[0-9]+\.[0-9]{3}s))/\1/"
4. sed -E "s/.*systemd\[1\]:.*([0-9]+min[[:space:]]+[0-9]+\.[0-9]{3}s|[0-9]+\.[0-9]{3}s)/\1/"
5. sed -E 's/.*systemd\[1\]:.*(([0-9]+min[[:space:]]+[0-9]+\.[0-9]{3}s)|([0-9]+\.[0-9]{3}s)).*/\1\3/'

Here is what happens:
1, 3, and 4: match only the 2.812s part independent of min part.
2: matches only if the min part is present (this makes sense)
5: same as 1,3 and 4, but twice. Which makes sense somehow
So, I am at a loss how I can match both lines with the min part present and lines with no min part.
Help?

Making the minutes optional lets sed apply the .* maximally greedily and skip them entirely. The easy fix is to require some sort of anchor, such as the equals sign just before the string you want to capture.
sed -E "s/.*systemd\[1\]:.*= (([0-9]+min[[:space:]])?[0-9]+\.[0-9]{3}s)/\1/"

Notice also how I refactored the parentheses around the optional minutes.
Generally, I would recommend single quotes around your sed scripts if you are using a Unix-style shell, but I did not change that here.
Demo: https://ideone.com/Dwu5Xl

Thanks, that works! So just to understand correctly: the = sign just works to 'break up' the greediness of the regex, i.e. stops .* from matching so I can start with my expression to match the timestamp, correct?

Yeah, that's the long and the short of it.

okay, then I could make the expression even easier by using:.*= ([0-9]+.*)\.$

If you use awk instead of sed for this part then you won't need grep for the first part, you won't need another tool for the next part (determining averages), and the resulting script will be clearer, more robust, more efficient, and more portable than the one you'll end up with if you keep going down your current path.
For example, the following, using GNU awk for various extensions, will output a CSV of totals and averages for all of the tags found on each "Startup finished in " line, no need to grep before it:
$ cat ./tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    BEGIN { OFS="," }

    match($0,/.*Startup finished in (.*) \(([^)]+)) \+ (.*) \(([^)]+)) \+ (.*) \(([^)]+)) \+ (.*) \(([^)]+)) = (.*)\./,a) {
        a[10] = "total"

        for ( i=2; i<=10; i+=2 ) {
            tag = a[i]
            split(a[i-1], dur)

            for ( j in dur ) {
                durPart = dur[j]
                totSecs[tag] += (durPart ~ /min/ ? 60 : 1) * durPart
            }
        }
        ++numVals
    }

    END {
        print "Tag", "Tot", "Ave"
        for ( i=2; i<=10; i+=2 ) {
            tag = a[i]
            secs = totSecs[tag]
            print tag, secs, (numVals ? secs / numVals : 0)
        }
    }
' "${@:--}"


$ ./tst.sh file
Tag,Tot,Ave
firmware,77.344,15.4688
loader,19.686,3.9372
kernel,1546.55,309.31
userspace,87.657,17.5314
total,1731.25,346.249

